# How to properly execute a mysql query with one argument

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

I'm writing code to commit the members of a discord server into a mysql database using the python-mysql connector and discord.py

Here is my code

```
if message.content == "c!loadmembers" and message.author.id == 409535907788750859:
        try:
            for member in message.guild.members:
                query = "INSERT INTO users (name, msgs) VALUES (%s,0)"
                cursor.execute(query, (member.name, ))
                mydb.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

this returns: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement

When I use cursor.executemany() it makes rows each consisting of the individual characters of the command issuer, which is not what I'm looking for. [example of what I don't want](https://prnt.sc/pucaiu)

I essentially want rows in the table user each with the name of the users. Ex:

```
Table organized as: ID, Name, timesspoken, timestamp
Row1: 1, John, 0, timestamp
row2: 2, Bob, 0, timestamp
```

etc

How would I go about altering my code to get to this?

Thank you in advance.

Oh and im aware that Im not using commands properly and Im aware that I'm not using IDs of the people instead of their names. I'll fix that after I get this working

Comment: You could/should have added your comment as an edit to the post.

Comment: Can you verify the data type of `member.name`? Put this statement at the top of your loop: `print(type(member.name))` and show us the result.

Comment: @mypetlion it is a string

Comment: Any idea anyone?

Comment: If it's a fixed argument why use a placeholder?
`query = "INSERT INTO users (name, 0) VALUES (%s)"`

Comment: Also note that you database handling is blocking, you should switch to async wrappers